# fuzzy installed successfully but fuzzy.Soundex(4) has problems in python

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, soundex

Code:

```
>>> import fuzzy
>>> soundex = fuzzy.Soundex(4)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    soundex = fuzzy.Soundex(4)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Soundex'
```

I really don't know why, please help if you know about it!

Comment: What does `import fuzzy; print(fuzzy.__file__)` give?

Comment: Here:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyfuzzy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg\fuzzy\__init__.pyc       what can I know fron this?